# Howto customize CCL (Cast Companion Library) controller dialog

Tags: android, ccl

I'm trying to customize casting controller dialog and I have problems changing dialog's title style. I've implemented it like CCL library does but without success.

This is my relevant code:

**VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog.java**

```
public VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog(Context context) {
super(context, xxx.xxx.R.style.TTNCastDialog);
...
}
```

**VideoMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment.java**

```
public class VideoMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment extends MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment {

@Override
public VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog customControllerDialog = new VideoMediaRouteControllerDialog(context);
customControllerDialog.setVolumeControlEnabled(false);
return customControllerDialog;
}
```

}

**VideoMediaRouteDialogFactory.java**

```
public class VideoMediaRouteDialogFactory extends MediaRouteDialogFactory {

@Override
public VideoMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
return new VideoMediaRouteControllerDialogFragment();
}

}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TTNCastDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TTNCastDialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TTNCastDialogWindowTitle">
<item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/ccl_mr_custom_title</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml(v21)**

```
<style name="TTNCastDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TTNCastDialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

I've taken a look at MediaRouteThemeHelper's getButtonTextColor method

and it returns accent color instead of primary color. My application theme extends of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

I've tried this way too

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TTNCastDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TTNCastDialogWindowTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TTNCastDialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ccl_mr_custom_title</item>
    </style>
```

But it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks﻿

Comment: What version of the mediarouter support library are youusing

Comment: com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.0

Comment: @user5536184 did you find a solution?

Comment: @user5536184 I posted a similar question and didn't get any response, were you able to find a solution?